# Removing Indexes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-index

Using ArcGIS , I'm trying to automate a process to remove indexes from a dataset using the ArcGIS Modelbuilder. Is it possible to use a dataset (not a feature class) as an input parameter? Or would I have to put each feature class of the dataset as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [help page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/remove-attribute-index.htm) it has to be at the feature class level (not dataset):

> The table containing the index or indexes to be deleted. Table can
>   refer to an actual table, a feature class attribute table, or an
>   attributed relationship class.

Comment: great! Thanks alot , i saw that also. i was just wondering if anyone may have done it at the dataset level.